# get_avatar alternative for Buddypress's uploaded photo

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using the following snippet in my theme to get the logged-in user's avatar of the default wp user's setting page.

```
<?php echo get_avatar($id_or_email, $size='64', $default, $alt='User name' ); ?>
```

However, After installing the buddypress; I wanted to display the uploaded profile's photo of the user where the above snippet only shows the default wp avatar.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BuddyPress function `bp_core_fetch_avatar`

```
$user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $user_id) );
```

Review the function in `bp-core/bp-core-avatars.php` to see the available arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable both options:

```
<?php 
if ( empty ( bp_loggedin_user_id() == false ) ) {
    $user_id = bp_loggedin_user_id();
    echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $user_id) );
} else {
    echo get_avatar($id_or_email, $size='64', $default, $alt='User name' ); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. this is also a very useful idea.